# How can we convert this sql query into MongoDB query?

Tags: sql, mongodb, analytics, database

Let's suppose I have a collection which tracks the number of visits of a product for every customer email id. How can I convert the following query into `MongoDB` query.

```
select product_id, count(customer_email) 
       from table_sample 
       group by product_id.
```

I'm completely a novice at `MongoDB`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried. It would help us correct you and advise you better.

Comment: Did you try this (https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) ?

Comment: Thanks @somallg. This clarified the concept a little better.

Comment: @SwatiK use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34282729/edit) link on your question to add sample document with the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
db.table_sample.aggregate( [
   {
     $group: {
        _id: "$product_id",
        count: { $sum: 1 }
     }
   }
] )
```

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/

Comment: I'm getting this error; NameError: global name 'count' is not defined